# Cannot find module 'babelify' from redux-saga-beginner-tutorial

Tags: javascript, compilation

> redux-saga-beginner-tutorial@0.0.0 start C:\Users\brian\react\redux-saga-beginner-tutorial
>   budo main.js:build.js --dir ./ --verbose  --live -- -t babelify

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'babelify' from 'C:\Users\brian\react\redux-saga-beginner-tutorial'
    at C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:51:31
    at processDirs (C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:185:39)
    at ondir (C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:200:13)
    at load (C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:83:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:108:17)
    at C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:12:69
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\browserify\index.js:368:34
    at C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:53:13
    at processDirs (C:\Users\brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\budo\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:185:39)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)

Answer (score 3):

You probably needs to install it then :

```
npm install --save-dev babelify @babel/core
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Start all over doesn't work either. My friend following same steps and it works for him. I'm guessing something wrong with my local env, but don't know what it is.

Comment: Further examination shows that my npm installation is not complete. For my friend, his package list is very long while mine is very short. Not sure why npm installation failed. It did produced warning messages on deprecated packages and vulnerabilities, but it is not relevant because everybody gets the same warnings.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace ? Do you know which package installation failed ?

Comment: Worked great for me - thank you @BernardPagoaga 8^)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my environment variable was messed up and it was doing release build instead of dev build